# Что если использовать как lock объект коллекцию потоков которые работают?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть коллекция потоков:

```
private final List<Thread> monsters = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

В момент когда все эти потоки работают я хочу проверить их на `isAlive()` и чтобы не тревожить `ConcurrentModificationException`, я достаю их таким способом:

```
private List<Thread> getMonsters() {
    synchronized (this.monsters) {
        return new ArrayList<>(this.monsters);
    }
}
```

Но вот что меня беспокоит: если я блокирую объект `monsters` то я так же блокирую и его содержимое, и что произойдет если в момент выполнения критической секции, один из объектов потоков захочет изменить состояние? А он заблокирован в составе `monsters`...

Можно ли вообще так написать?

Или может быть синхронизация здесь вообще не нужна, и `CopyOnWriteArrayList` решит эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы вешаете `synchronized` на коллекцию содержащую потоки, то ничего страшного не должно произойти. Треды не будут блокироваться, они продолжат работать, конечно, если они не используют код, который тоже использует данную коллекцию как объект лока.

По поводу итерации. Вы используете **thread-safe** коллекцию `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Можете использовать ее безбоязненно в многопоточном окружении, это безопасно. Касательно, этой реализации, при вызове `iterator()`,  произойдет создание новой коллекции, содержащей элементы, которые были в исходной коллекции на момент создания.

Answer (score 2):

Смысл `CopyOnWriteArrayList` в том, что операции влияющие на изменение данных в коллекции никогда не дадут **ConcurrentModificationException**.

Также это справедливо для итерирования по коллекции. Чтобы проверить все потоки на `isAlive()` просто смело используйте `foreach` цикл или получайте `Iterator` и пробегайтесь по коллекции. При получении итератора из данной коллекции все элементы копируются, что приводит к потокобезопасному итерированию.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не блокируете ни объект `monsters`, ни его содержимое. На самом деле вы вообще ничего не блокируете. Все, что вы делаете, это захватываете монитор на объекте `monsters`. И пока не придет другой поток и не попытается захватить монитор на том же самом объекте, ничего и нигде заблокировано не будет. А вот когда другой поток все-таки придет, и монитор окажется захваченным, то этот поток будет заблокирован до тех пор, пока монитор не освободится.

Во-вторых, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` сам будет потокобезопасно создавать копию на каждую модификацию коллекции. Так что вам, в данном случае, не нужна дополнительная синхронизация.

Answer (score 1):

-если в программе элементы добавляются в одном месте и коллекция больше не изменяется - такой синхронизации не нужно
-если хочешь подождать завершения потоков, можно использовать

```
for(int i = 0;i<monsters.size();i++){
   try{
      monsters.get(i).join();
   }catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
```

-если количество элементов известно, можно использовать `Thread[] monsters = new Thread[count];`
-если не нужен доступ/вставка элементов в конкретное место `Queue`/`Deque`
-не будет прироста производительности если потоков в приложении больше чем потоков в устройстве
P.S. сам экспериментировал, тут мои домыслы о твоей задаче/идеи для реализации